# How to parse a Nested JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Thank you reading my post, I known this topic was asked so many time, and I had saw that but no luck...

I want to parse a simple JSON string, as followings:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name_en":"Photography",
      "subchannels":[
         {
            "id":"4",
            "name_en":"John"
         },
         {
            "id":"18",
            "name_en":"Sam"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
      "name_en":"Equipment",
      "subchannels":[
         {
            "id":"25",
            "name_en":"ABC Company"
         },
         {
            "id":"40",
            "name_en":"CDE Company"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

It had convert this string to NSDictionary

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *testDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&e];
```

Then I list the Dictionary Key

```
for(id key in testDic) {
        NSLog(@"%@", key);
    }
```

The result is the entire record as the Dictionary Key, so I can't use [testDic objectForKey:key] to retrieve the value.

How can I get the first row name_en and the second row subchannels value?
(is it possible to retrieve easily like xpath in XML?)

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your JSON represents an *array*, not a dictionary - could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. The root object of your model is `NSArray` object - not `NSDictionary. '[]' means array and {} means dictionary.

```
NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&e];

for (NSDictionary *entry in dataArray) {
  NSString *name = entry[@"name_en"];
  NSArray *subchannels = entry[@"subchannels"]; //array of dictionaries

  NSLog(@"Name %s", name); 

  for  (NSDictionary *subchannel in subchannels) {
     NSLog(@"Subchannels name %@ id: %d", subchannel[@"name"], [subchannel[@"id"] integerValue]);
  }
}
```

If you want to perform advances JSON parsing I encourage you to look at [Mantle github project](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle).

Comment: WOW~ thank you very much, It Works~~~~~~ Thank you Rafal, also thank to Greg~

Comment: I got stuck trying to solve a similar problem; your comment there @Rafal Augustyniak, that the first part [] is an array and second part {} is dictionary really saved me! I was treating everything as an array!